# searching and sorting

Tags: search

If the list has 1024 items (lg1024 = 10) at what point (the number of searches) does sorting the list first and using binary search pay off? How does your answer change if the list has 2048 items? instead of using sequential search

Comment: This looks like homework

Comment: not homework trying to teach myself algorithm design

Comment: it might not be a homework. i once solved this task in real life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the "linear access" curve crosses the "binary search" curve depends on how long it takes to access/insert a single item versus how many items there are. This will be different for every combination of compiler, memory and cpu architecture, type of data/node in the list, the distribution of data values, what sort and insertion algorithms you use, etc...  But with a "large enough" set of items, the running time can be described by mentioning how its upper bound grows with increasing number of items, even though that "Big-O" bound may not precisely describe any particular run.

You can figure out precisely if you can know the specific algorithm you will insert or search with, and determine the actual instructions that make up your list accesses, and find out how many clock cycles they take to execute, etc etc...

Then you can say for sure which one is faster, and at which point. And if you know you data values, you can model it.  But if you don't know, you have to assume (for example, what if your inserted data values are already ordered? how does that affect your sort or insertion function?)

For example, a single item retrieval may take 1us. Comparing two items may take 0.5us. Doing a sorted list insertion with 100 items in the list might require X number of retrievals, Y number of compares, and Z number of updates/writes.... Whereas an unordered list might require more or less depending on what's already there and what you're inserting.

Answer (score 1):

if your list is unsorted it will take O(n) to find it. Sort with quicksort costs O(n*log n), then binary search is O(log n). Lets assume that x is number of searchs. `x * n = x * logn + n * logn` . by putting different values you can estimate the dynamics. my rough estimate tells that if n = 1024 and number searches is greater then ~10, it is more efficitent to sort first. put 1024 instead of n and try.

Comment: I think the equation should be: x * n = n * logn + x * logn

Comment: I get ~10 when n=1024 and ~11 when n=1024.